# Remove row from DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net

In order to initialize my VouchersDGV Data Grid View I'm Using the following

```
 DGV.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
 For i = 1 To DGV.RowCount - 1
     DGV.Rows.Remove(DGV.Rows(i - 1))
     DGV.Refresh()
 Next
```

But when I'm runing it for the first time I take the error of

> {"Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted."} System.InvalidOperationException

If I will continue and run my code and write a new row in my Data Grid and I will try to initialize again (now I have two rows, one has the data and the other is empty) I take this error

> {"Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted."} System.InvalidOperationException

I can't solve it, Please is there someone to assist me on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If Not DGV.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
    DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
End If
```

Add this condition to your loop. Alternatively, you could also use DGV.RejectChanges() which will reset all the row status to original.

Comment: @Dear Mohib, I did what you propose me BUT having the following condition. Row(0) has all the columns with data, Row(1) is there without data in columns. I give the command DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(0) and return me the error DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(0) {"Operation cannot be performed in this event handler."} System.InvalidOperationException. Please assist me on this issue.

Comment: Private Sub VouchersDGV_RowValidating

Comment: I also run it in another Handler. RaiseEvent EscapeOnFirstRowPressed(). Which is run very well when i call it from inside the row

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to empty the row collection, you can just use the Clear method of the Rows collection:

`DGV.Rows.Clear()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did your solution as well BUT it returns me the error.   VouchersDGV.Rows.Clear() {"Operation cannot be performed in this event handler."} System.InvalidOperationException. What I shall do with that?

Comment: @Lefteris: I did not realize that you had this code in the RowValidating event handler. Could you please clarify the use case you want to implement with this datagrid, especially how and when rows should be deleted?

Comment: Sorry for my delay. You see when I'm leaving the row (in the 7nth Cell) I want to write the data in a file (that is done it) and automatically delete the current row to bring the DataGridView to its initial position.