# remove rows containing string

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, remove-if

I would like to know how i can remove these rows insted of making them green

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'test
    Dim examplea As String = "PAID"
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If examplea = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("PROJECT").Value.ToString Then
                ' MessageBox.Show("record already exist")
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.green
                'DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
            Else
                ''MsgBox("N-E")
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'test
End Sub
```

Comment: `"making them red"` am I missing where this is at in your code?

Comment: does the DGV use a datasource or is it manually populated?

Comment: Sorry I mean green and the datagrid is manually poulated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove row from DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950205/remove-row-from-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am entirely understanding what you need except you want to remove a row...

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'test
    Dim examplea As String = "PAID"
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       For i = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If examplea = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("PROJECT").Value.ToString Then
                ' MessageBox.Show("record already exist")
                'DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.green
                DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
            Else
                ''MsgBox("N-E")
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'test
End Sub
```

Comment: well what i need is to remove the row if it says PAID in its project column

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT an important thing to note is that you must iterate backwards in order to evaluate all the rows if you will be removing any